# Express.js rest api not working on heroku

Tags: node.js, rest, express, heroku

I've written a basic node.js application, it's working on local with the command : node app.js but not in heroku here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "express-rest-youness",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-rest": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

and my app.js

```
 var express = require('express'),
    expressRest = require('express-rest');

 var app = express();
var rest = expressRest(app);

var records = [
    {value: 'Apple'},
    {value: 'Banana'}
];

rest.get('/api/food', function(req, rest) {
    rest.ok(records);
});

rest.get('/api/food/:id', function(req, rest) {
    var record = records[req.params.id];
    if (record) rest.ok(record);
    else rest.notFound();
});

rest.put('/api/food/:id', function(req, rest) {
    records[req.params.id] = req.body;
    return rest.accepted('/api/food/' + encodeURI(req.params.id));
});

rest.post('/api/food', function(req, rest) {
    records.push(req.body);
    rest.created('/api/food/' + (records.length - 1));
});

rest.delete('/api/food/:id', function(req, rest) {
    delete records[req.params.id];
    rest.gone();
})


app.listen(8080);
```

when trying to access the heroku app i get :

Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you created a Procfile? I'd suggest to familiarize yourself with [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs).

Comment: Thanks, worked, i read before asking about the procfile but i was excepting the heroku run node app.js to work too .. anyway thanks a lot :)

Comment: @YounessHoudass you're very welcome. Would you mark my answer as the solution please ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by logging in into heroku dashboard and then app settings and there i specified config vars

Comment: You need to get more information on what the error is, such as requesting for the log message, then you can tell if this proffered solution fits into this scenario